# Why does print(users_dict.get("bob")) and print(users_dict.get(users[0].username)) print different results?

Tags: python

How does

```
print(users_dict.get("bob"))
```

and

```
print(users_dict.get(users[0].username))
```

print different values?

The `User` class is here

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, _id, username, password):
        self.id = _id,
        self.username = username,
        self.password = password
```

```
from user import User


users = [
    User(1, "bob", "123"),
    User(2, 'John', '456'),
    User(3, "Dan", '789')
]


users_dict = {u.username: u for u in users}


print(users_dict.get("bob"))      # prints None
print(users_dict.get(users[0].username))  # prints <user.User object at 0x7f29efa61f60>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully at the output of `print(users_dict)`, which is:

`{('bob',): <__main__.User object at 0x7f13c4d52e50>, ('John',): <__main__.User object at 0x7f13c4da49a0>, ('Dan',): <__main__.User object at 0x7f13c4cce790>}`

you'll notice that the key is not `'bob'`, it is `('bob',)`. And that's because of the comma in your class definition:

`self.username = username,`

(of course the comma in preceding line is also wrong).

Answer (score 3):

You have a comma `,` at the end of

```
self.username = username,
```

so, you define `self.username` as a tuple containing one item, `username`. Note that the comma makes the tuple, not the parentheses.

You can see it if you `print(users[1].username)`:

```
('John',)  # that's a tuple!
```

So, as `get` fails to find the key `'John'`, it returns its default value, `None`

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answers have mentioned, it is a tuple, not a string to which you should use to make this comparison.

First, if we look at the keys() of this dictionary:

```
print(users_dict.keys())
# dict_keys([('bob',), ('John',), ('Dan',)])
```

Each key is a tuple. So, to compare:

```
print(users_dict.get( ('bob',) ))
# gives out: <__main__.User ...>
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is because the key is different as u can see by printing
print(users_dict)